# Can I create vps(linux or windows) with higher ram than physical ram?

Tags: windows, centos, vmware, vps, ram

Can I create vps (Linux or windows) with higher ram than physical ram?
Suppose, I have a physical PC (CentOS) with 16 GM RAM. I want to install multiple OS on VPS. Every VPS having 8 GB RAM. Total 4 VPS, total 4x8=32 GB RAM require.  But none of the VPS OS take more than 4 GB RAM (I assumed). In this situation can I do it? My clients want to see 8 GB RAM and I manage their VPS. They (each vps) never used 8 GB RAM.
If not possible, is there any way to show RAM (8GB) more than actual RAM (4GB) in vmware/xenserver vps? 
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote this but someone might have because this is not a good question for StackOverflow. Maybe Serverfault?

Answer (score 0):

Can be created. Because your guest os all started unused 16GB RAM. You can run it. But if your guest os  fills up with 16GB of RAM, your VM will hang up, causing it to be unusable. vSphere,vcenter will recycle your RAM in a variety of ways, such as compression, forced occupancy, and balloon.